# Comparing two cells to mark if contents are actually different or just re-arranged?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 192-914-231 | 914-231-192 | FALSE |
| 192-914-231 | 914-187-231 | TRUE |

I have two columns in excel containing digits with hyphens between them. I need to compare these columns to see whether there is a difference in the numbers or if they are just rearranged. I would like this to return as FALSE- the number are just rearranged or TRUE- there is a difference in digits.

Above, row 1 is false since the 3-digit clusters just switched placed. Row 2 is True even though the places switched there was also a change in value. Could I get some guidance on a formula that'd be able to put this together?

I am currently doing this by eye, comparing the length and exact of the columns to help identify them, but haven't come up with a good way to do this via formula.

Comment: Try i think this is what you need using a formula: `=OR(SORT(TEXTSPLIT(A2,,"-"))<>SORT(TEXTSPLIT(B2,,"-")))`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya make that an answer please.  Much better than my longer method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I have commented above, here is an alternative using <kbd>TEXTSPLIT( )</kbd> & <kbd>SORT( )</kbd>

[image]

---

```
=OR(SORT(TEXTSPLIT(A2,,"-"))<>SORT(TEXTSPLIT(B2,,"-")))
```

---

Also, I will like to say thanks to two special peoples for whom I have learnt lot from this forum : **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir & **[Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner)** Sir, lot of support and knowledge I have gathered from them .

---

Or, as mentioned by @JvdV Sir :

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=MAP(A2:A3,B2:B3,LAMBDA(x,y,OR(SORT(TEXTSPLIT(x,,"-"))<>SORT(TEXTSPLIT(y,,"-")))))
```

---

Answer (score 2):

Just another alternative:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=REDUCE(B1:B4,{1,5,9},LAMBDA(x,y,SUBSTITUTE(x,MID(A1:A4,y,3),,1)))<>"--"
```